# Filter Pandas DataFrame by ip address range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ip-address

I need to filter a pandas `Dataframe` by the range of ip addresses. Is it possible with out regular expressions?

```
Ex. From 61.245.160.0   To 61.245.175.255
```

Comment: @Andy Hayden : Ok, fine with regex, I have lot of ranges to be matched, that is why i asked without regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are orderable in python, so you should be able to get away with just that:

```
In [11]: '61.245.160.0' < '61.245.175.255'
Out[11]: True
```

Either boolean mask:

```
In [12]: df[('61.245.160.0' < df.ip) & (df.ip < '61.245.175.255')]
```

or take a slice (if ip were the index):

```
In [13]: df.loc['61.245.160.0':'61.245.175.255']
```

Comment: I love python! The simplest possible solution is often actually available to the programmer!

Comment: Careful with this approach as it does not sort correctly.   i.e. `'61.245.160.99' < '61.245.160.102' Out[161]: False`

Comment: @adele good point, a quick ish way to get the right behaviour is to create a large number representative for an ip address e.g. `61 * 1000000000 + 245 * 1000000+ 160 * 1000 + 255` and sort based on that.

Comment: I agree with @ade1e. Why not using `import ipaddress`? It works nice: `[x for x in nets if (host2 >= x.network_address and host2 <= x.broadcast_address)]` . The only thing is I really do not know how to use this approach with Pandas.

Answer (score 4):

I have an approach using [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html).

For example, I want to know if `host0 = 10.2.23.5` belongs to any of the following networks `NETS  = ['10.2.48.0/25','10.2.23.0/25','10.2.154.0/24']`.

```
>>> host0 = ip.IPv4Address('10.2.23.5')
>>> NETS = ['10.2.48.0/25','10.2.23.0/25','10.2.154.0/24']
>>> nets  = [ip.IPv4Network(x) for x in NETS]
>>> [x for x in nets if (host2 >= x.network_address and host2 <= x.broadcast_address)]
[IPv4Network('10.2.23.0/25')]
```

Now, in order to get together this approach with Pandas, one shall do the following: create a function and apply it to each row of the DF.

```
def fnc(row):
    host = ip.IPv4Address(row)
    vec = [x for x in netsPy if (host >= x.network_address and host <= x.broadcast_address)]

    if len(vec) == 0:
        return '1'
    else:
        return '-1'
```

You later on apply it to the DF.

```
df['newCol'] = df['IP'].apply(fnc)
```

This will create a new column `newCol` where each row will be either `1` or `-1` , depending on whether the IP address belongs to either network of your interest.

Comment: import ipaddress as ip

Comment: The above code works when we specify two or more IP Ranges in NETS ? 
Like NETS = ['9.0.0.0/8', '90.0.0.0/8']
Also the netsPy in function is nets I assume

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]:
               ip
0    61.245.160.1
1  61.245.160.100
2  61.245.160.200
3  61.245.160.254
```

let's find all IPs falling between (but not including) `61.245.160.99` and `61.245.160.254`:

```
In [49]: ip_from = '61.245.160.99'

In [50]: ip_to = '61.245.160.254'
```

if we will compare IPs as strings - it will be compared lexicographically so it won't work properly as [@adele has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979109/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-ip-address-range#comment65706530_22979217):

```
In [51]: df.query("'61.245.160.99' < ip < '61.245.160.254'")
Out[51]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ip]
Index: []

In [52]: df.query('@ip_from < ip < @ip_to')
Out[52]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ip]
Index: []
```

We can use [numerical IP representation](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html#numerical-representation):

```
In [53]: df[df.ip.apply(lambda x: int(IPAddress(x)))
   ....:      .to_frame('ip')
   ....:      .eval('{} < ip < {}'.format(int(IPAddress(ip_from)),
   ....:                                  int(IPAddress(ip_to)))
   ....:       )
   ....: ]
Out[53]:
               ip
1  61.245.160.100
2  61.245.160.200
```

Explanation:

```
In [66]: df.ip.apply(lambda x: int(IPAddress(x)))
Out[66]:
0    1039507457
1    1039507556
2    1039507656
3    1039507710
Name: ip, dtype: int64

In [67]: df.ip.apply(lambda x: int(IPAddress(x))).to_frame('ip')
Out[67]:
           ip
0  1039507457
1  1039507556
2  1039507656
3  1039507710

In [68]: (df.ip.apply(lambda x: int(IPAddress(x)))
   ....:    .to_frame('ip')
   ....:    .eval('{} < ip < {}'.format(int(IPAddress(ip_from)),
   ....:                               int(IPAddress(ip_to))))
   ....: )
Out[68]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

PS here is a bit faster (vectorized) function which will return numerical IP representation:

```
def ip_to_int(ip_ser):
    ips = ip_ser.str.split('.', expand=True).astype(np.int16).values
    mults = np.tile(np.array([24, 16, 8, 0]), len(ip_ser)).reshape(ips.shape)
    return np.sum(np.left_shift(ips, mults), axis=1)
```

Demo:

```
In [78]: df['int_ip'] = ip_to_int(df.ip)

In [79]: df
Out[79]:
               ip      int_ip
0    61.245.160.1  1039507457
1  61.245.160.100  1039507556
2  61.245.160.200  1039507656
3  61.245.160.254  1039507710
```

check:

```
In [80]: (df.ip.apply(lambda x: int(IPAddress(x))) == ip_to_int(df.ip)).all()
Out[80]: True
```

Comment: Just wanted to add, I have encountered a problem with `def ip_to_int(ip_ser)` when my IP was eg. `240.42.123.100`, I would get int `-265651356`. This was caused due to an integer overflow of `np.left_shift(ips, mults)`. I found a work around using https://stackoverflow.com/a/27400252/6453903 with `np.left_shift(ips.astype(object), mults)` in this case