# Left shifting 1 by large numbers using numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, bit-shift

Python can indeed left shift a bit by large integers

```
1L << 100
# 1267650600228229401496703205376L
```

But NumPy seemingly has a problem:

```
a = np.array([1,2,100])
output = np.left_shift(1L,a)
print output 
# array([          2,           4, 68719476736])
```

Is there a way to overcome this using NumPy's left_shift operation? Individually accessing the array elements gives the same incorrect result:

```
1L << a[2]
# 68719476736
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `long` values aren't the same type as the integers held in `a`. Specifically, Python `long` values are not limited to 32 bits or 64 bits but instead can take up an arbitrary amount of memory.

On the other hand, NumPy will create `a` as an array of `int32` or `int64` integer values. When you left-shift this array, you get back an array of the same datatype. This isn't enough memory to hold `1 << 100` and the result of the left-shift overflows the memory it's been allocated in the array, producing the incorrect result.

To hold integers that large, you'll have to specify `a` to have the `object` datatype. For example:

```
>>> np.left_shift(1, a.astype(object))
array([2, 4, 1267650600228229401496703205376L], dtype=object)
```

`object` arrays can hold a mix of different types, including the unlimited-size Python `long`/integer values. However, a lot of the performance benefits of homogeneous datatype NumPy arrays will be lost when using `object` arrays.

Comment: One minor correction: Integers in python (as in `int`, but the docs use `integer` somewhat as a synonym for `int`). `long`s act as you described. That said, the code here uses `long` types and python uses `long` if your literal is too big for `int`. Your statement just confused me, and I wanted to spare others to look it up at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: @kratenko - thank you, I should have made that clearer. I had in mind Python 3 where the `long` type has disappeared (I see now that the question is tagged Python 2.7).

Comment: ah, and I didn't know that about Python 3. I really should take a look at 3 some time soon...

Comment: Saying "the `long` type has disappeared in Python 3" may mislead. In Python 3 the built-in `int` type has no theoretical upper limit on size, so essentially `long` has been integrated into `int`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/2234) with 64-bit Python too, except that the integer at which this becomes a problem is larger. if you run `a[2]=1L << a[2]` you will get this Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

So as the traceback says *Python int too large to convert to C long* , so you need to change the array type (that is actually C structure ) to an python object :

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,100],dtype='O')
>>> a[2]=1L << a[2]
>>> a
array([1, 2, 1267650600228229401496703205376L], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the array `a` you create, the elements of `output` are going to be integers. Unlike Python itself, integers in a numpy darray are of fixed size with a defined maximum and minimum value.

numpy is arriving at the value given (`2 ** 36`) by reducing the shift modulo the length of the integer, 64 bits (100 mod 64 == 36).